# Published and updated mass email statistics?

Tags: security, email, spam

I'm wondering if someone is publishing statistics on email usage on the internet.

The main number I'm looking for is average message size on a large scale sample data over time.

If someone doing spam/security checks is accumulating this data and publishing it I'd like to know.

Barracuda, Trend, Symantec, SpamCop, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a lot of info like that from Cisco's [Senderbase](http://www.senderbase.org/)

Comment: Thanks for the link, although it is not quite what I'm looking for.  I'd like more aggregated statistics about the messages themselves, this is more about the senders.